# Auto-layout in UITableViewCell: make UITextView appear only if content not null

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

In my project, I have three types of custom UITableViewCells. One for text-only, one for text + url and one for text + image. I am using auto-layout with IOS 8.0 and am trying to use constraints to make the text block only appear if not null. The text being before url and image I don't want to get an extra useless space.

Is it the right way to go or should I implement two new types for image-only and url-only?

I have been trying to set up height >= 0 for the text block in the constraints but it keeps be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the text view to take up space, remove it from the cell for that row. Of course, for rows where the text view is needed, if it is absent, you will have to add it. Making the constraints correct will also be up to you.

Comment: That's what I meant by new type of cell. Is there no way to make it automatic if text is empty? Otherwise yes I can add a new type of cell where text is absent. But that would mean there are now 5 types of cells. And if later I want to add something else that once again is not necessatily available for all cells that would mean 10 types and so on ... it gets very messy. I was hoping to get something smart (no content ? auto-layout makes height 0)

Comment: By type I mean cell identifier as you probably understood.

Comment: Listen to what I said. I said _don't_ use another type of cell. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, where the cell meets its content, you can configure the cell's interior. Configure it! Remove the text view or add it, depending on whether there is text or not, and reconfigure the constraints accordingly. The cell will then size itself correctly.